# iOS does not detect new peripheral name

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, cbperipheral

We are using CC2540 BLE Chip as peripheral and an iOS 7.0.4 iPhone is playing central role.

We change the peripheral name, but this change is only shown when we disconnect from iOS device and reconnect.

It works fine in Android using this code to change peripheral name in response data:

```
GAPRole_SetParameter( GAPROLE_SCAN_RSP_DATA, sizeof ( deviceName ), deviceName );
```

We are using this code to change the peripheral name of GAP layer in iOS:

```
GGS_SetParameter( GGS_DEVICE_NAME_ATT, GAP_DEVICE_NAME_LEN, attDeviceName );
```

Is there any way to change peripheral name so that no reconnection is needed?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Who is playing the Central role and who is playing the peripheral one?

Comment: Another question. What are you using for testing iOS, your own code or some BLE app from the appstore?

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana Sorry I have edited my question. We have tested with our own code and with LightBlue app. I suppose LightBlue uses peripheral.name property at the first table too.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana. It was useful somehow, because I have checked that even removing all peripherals and scanning again I still have the old peripheral name. I vote your proposal for it. However, I still can not get the new name from peripheral.name. I have managed to get it from advertisementData:

    NSObject *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem is in the iOS App code.

The basic order of calls to connect in iOS to BLE is:

```
centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
                                                    options: nil];
```

this last one invokes:

```
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
```

then if central.state is CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn you can:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil 
                                       options:nil];
```

this last one invokes:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

Apple here recommends: "You must retain a local copy of the peripheral if any command is to be performed on it."

That means you should create a property for your CBPeripheral like:

self.myPeripheral = peripheral;

It is here where you have a peripheral.name or self.myPeripheral.name

If you don't call again in your code: [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil                                           options:nil]; what you have is the information retrieved the first time. You should make the call again if you want to refresh the name. Maybe with a timer.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

Check: [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide: Performing Common Central Role Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have removed all peripherals, then scan for peripherals again, and old name remains.

Comment: Then it is a problem in the peripheral. It is a problem that the peripheral is populating.

Comment: I think I'll try to get the name from advertisementData.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the local name from advertisementData. There is the solution: [Incorrect BLE Peripheral Name with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938274/incorrect-ble-peripheral-name-with-ios)

And on Apple Developer Forums, here is the detail of `CBPeripheral` `name` property.

Comment: The Apple Developer Forums link: [https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19381](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19381)